# Prism : Shell regions view change not reflecting in xaml view

Tags: wpf, module, prism, region, bootstrapper

I am defining two regions in shell: MainRegion and ToggleRegion. The Toggle region contains a button on clicking on that button i want to change the region in Main Region.

Here is my xaml code for registering regions in shell.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"></ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="ToggleRegion"></ContentControl>

</Grid>
```

My Bootstrapper add MainModule where I am injecting view in Region

```
  protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        var catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
        catalog.AddModule(typeof (MainModule));
                   return catalog;
    }
```

My MainModule class

```
 public void Initialize()
    {
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(MainView));
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ToggleRegion", typeof(ToggleView));

     }
```

On Running the application I can see MainView and ToggleView loaded in MainRegion and ToggleRegion. But when i click the button  in toggle region to change the view in Main region. Main region view is not changing.

Code in my button click event

```
{
     IRegion region = regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"];

        var view = region.Views.SingleOrDefault();
        region.Remove(view);
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(ViewOnButtonClick));
        region.Activate(view);
```

}

On debugging I can see region is removing MainView first then activating viewonbuttonclick but same is not reflecting in my xaml View.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
var view = region.Views.SingleOrDefault();
    region.Remove(view);
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(ViewOnButtonClick));
    region.Activate(view);
```

What I would do is register all the views upfront..

```
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(MainView));
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ToggleRegion", typeof(ToggleView));
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(ViewOnButtonClick));
```

and then instead of removing a view from the region get the view by the view name you've given it.. and then activate

```
      var view = region.Views.SingleOrDefault(v => v != null && v.GetType() == typeof     (ViewOnButtonClick); 

      region.Activate(view);
```

Comment: Earlier I was doing the same but that also didn't yield me result. Infact when i stop at just region.Remove(view) with no view inside Main Region. region does get empty with no view but same is not reflecting in my xaml shell. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with my Bootstrapper Class. I was starting the application like this:-

```
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        Shell shell = new Shell();
       Application.Current.MainWindow = null;
       Application.Current.StartupUri = new Uri("Shell.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
       return (DependencyObject)shell;
    }
```

Using shell.show() instead of current.startupuri allow me to change the view on button click.